# More than one intent-filter with category DEFAULT

Tags: android, android-manifest

Read the documentation but unclear as to the purpose of the DEAFAULT category in the manifest. Is it possible to have more than 1 intent-filter with the DEFAULT category attribute in the same manifest?

Comment: it's the default category for each activity whatever you set it or not but if you starting activity implicitly you can't   call this activity because when Android filter it will find any intent-filter in this activity to return it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have more than one.  From the documentation here is why you would need the default category:

*Note: In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you do not declare this category in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve to your activity.* - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Example of having more than one intent filter with default category:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="myscheme"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have more than 1 intent-filter with the DEFAULT category attribute in the same manifest?

Sure. Most activities that have an `<intent-filter>` will support the `DEFAULT` category, as that category is automatically added to an `Intent` used with `startActivity()` if there is no other category on the `Intent` already.

For example, in [the manifest for the AOSP Music app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music.git/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml), you can see a variety of `<activity>` elements, with and without `<intent-filter>` elements. Those that have `<intent-filter>` may or may not use `DEFAULT`.

Comment: In what situations (and why?) might the filter not use default (other than CATEGORY_LAUNCHER for adding icons and usually ACTION_MAIN as well)? I'm a newbie, so I might be missing the obvious, but I thought the point to intent-filter tags was to resolve implicit intents. I'd also like to know if this view extends to other components like services and broadcast receivers. I'd be very grateful if you point me in the right direction.

Comment: @batbrat: "In what situations (and why?) might the filter not use default" -- categories in general are usually only used for activities, though there's nothing stopping someone from applying them to services or broadcast receivers. There are a handful of common categories, which you'll find listed in the `Intent` documentation (e.g., `CATEGORY_BROWSEABLE`).

Comment: right! I've seen the documentation. The thing is, CATEGORY_BROWSABLE would have to be used with CATEGORY_DEFAULT as well. Otherwise, it would make no sense, except, perhaps as a form of documentation. That's how it seemed to me, and that's why I'm asking. Should I start a new question?

Comment: @batbrat: "The thing is, CATEGORY_BROWSABLE would have to be used with CATEGORY_DEFAULT as well" -- I am not aware that this is a requirement. "Should I start a new question?" -- probably, though I would have to guess that this has been covered already in another question.

Comment: thanks for the input. I'll do more digging. As for them being used together, it's not a requirement, but it makes no sense not to, at least, to me. Afaik, that would be pointless. Anyway, I'll do more digging. Thanks again.